# why does my loop only iterate properly with alerts in the loop?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I'm writing a loop in a mobile app that vibrates the phone in a certain pattern, to be repeated a number of times as specified by the user. See the code below:

```
do
{   
    navigator.vibrate([200,200,200,200,200,1000]);  
    //alert("v" + vibrator); 
    //alert("a" + alert_number);
    vibrator++;
}
while (vibrator < alert_number);
```

Now, with the alerts commented out the pattern is only 'vibrated' once, regardless of the value of alert_number (the number of times the pattern is to be repeated). If I have the alerts() active, the pattern repeats the correct amount of times, albeit with a few presses on the alerts to close the pop ups, which I don't want. Can anyone tell me why having alerts would affect the operation of the loops?

Comment: sounds like you need to add delays

Comment: So essentially what's happening is that the patterns of vibrations are all happening at the same time, over each other? I thought that might have been the case but was struggling to come up with the best manner to delay them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)  in this instance as you need a delay between each vibration otherwise it will all just happen 'all at once'.

E.g.

```
var vibrator = 0;
var v_id = setInterval(function() {
    navigator.vibrate([200,200,200,200,200,1000]);
    if(vibrator++ == alert_number) {
        clearInterval(v_id);
    }
}, 250);
```